# Can i dynamically perform php actions using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am wondering whether it is possible to perform a php action, on a button click without refreshing the page, using jQuery.

I have tried doing something like this:

Html:

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    <?php
       echo "test";
   ?>
});
```

However nothing happens on the button click. I am aware of AJAX, but am just wondering if it is possible with jQuery?

Comment: Directly the way you have asked, no. That's not possible.  PHP is server side while JS is client side.  AJAX is the way you would need to do that.

Comment: No. jQuery is client side PHP is server side. However, indirectly, it is possible by calling for other pages or by some sort of API.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Thank you for the quick response. And okay, i was just wondering if it was possible.

Comment: You're welcome.  Are you familiar enough with AJAX to do this correctly?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup I have learned a very little amount AJAX, and don't know how to do it.

Comment: Jorge's answer provides a very basic example and the link to learn some more.  Good luck and post another question if you need help after trying yourself.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Okay great. Ill go check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you need ajax,

```
$.ajax({url: "action.php", success: function(result){
    console.log(result);
}});
```

for more information

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you! I'll check out the link you gave to learn more AJAX.